# Calendar throwing TypeError: Cannot read property "4" from undefined. (line 30)

Tags: google-apps-script

So the following script works fine if the calendar has no events in the selected range. Once this is ran once and all events post correctly. Say if there was a change in the schedule and the same range is ran through the script it throws the following error. I'm just a little puzzled at why that error and not a Calendar Error.  If you clear out the calendar manually, and re-run the script it will post correctly.

TypeError: Cannot read property "4" from undefined. (line 30)

Code:

```
function addCrewsToCalendar() {
var humCalendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(ScriptProperties.getProperty('humCalendar'));
var glsCalendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(ScriptProperties.getProperty('glsCalendar'));

var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getValues();

for (var i in range){
//Date Params
var startTime = range[i][1];
var endTime = range[i][2];
var recurrence = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addDailyRule().times(7);

//Houma Air Crew
var humSO = range[i][3];
var humRS1 = range[i][5];
var humRSw = range[i][7];

//Set Houma Calendar

//Post Houma Schedule
humCalendar.createAllDayEventSeries('HUM RS1: '+humRS1, startTime, recurrence);
humCalendar.createAllDayEventSeries('HUM SO: '+humSO, startTime, recurrence);
humCalendar.createAllDayEventSeries('HUM RSw: '+humRSw, startTime, recurrence);

//Galveston Air Crew    
var glsSO = range[i][4];
var glsRS1 = range[i][6];
var glsRSw = range[i][8];

//Set Galveston Calendar
//Remove any events so there are no duplicates
var glsEvents = glsCalendar.getEvents(startTime, endTime);
for (var i in glsEvents){
  glsEvents[i].deleteEvent();
}
//Post GLS Schedule
glsCalendar.createAllDayEventSeries('GLS RS1: '+glsRS1, startTime, recurrence);
glsCalendar.createAllDayEventSeries('GLS SO: '+glsSO, startTime, recurrence);
glsCalendar.createAllDayEventSeries('GLS RSw: '+glsRSw, startTime, recurrence);    

}


}
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

Thanks Ahead of time.

Comment: What's line 30? Error hints at var glsSO = range[i][4];, but your code snippet points to a comment.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
var glsSO = range[i][4];
```

is accessing property 4 of variable. It seems that the variable range[i] isn't defined for some reason.

Comment: Right but it is defined when you first run it.  The scheduler goes and selects the rows he wants to post.  But if it is posting a range that the calendar already has an event for it stops right there every time.  Then if I clear all the events in that date range it will run with out errors, and it's not specific to a certain date, if you were to select different rows you would get the same result if they had already been written to the calendar.

Comment: Tried answering my own question but, not enough rep. I was using [i] inside another for statement, changed the in the for loops to [j]. Problem solved. Thanks Guys.